# How can I show a link-ike text to open the Explorer to upload files/folders?

Tags: javascript, html, input, file-upload

I am trying to implement an upload-function but instead of the input I want to show a text for example `Drop Folder` instead of the default  `Choose File <Filename> Upload` using input like this:

```
    <div class="upload-folder" style="display:inline">
        <input type="file"
               id="file"
               webkitdirectory 
               multiple
               (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
    
        <button (click)="uploadFiles()">Upload</button>
    </div>
```

How can I display the text `Drag Folder` with a ClickListener which opens the Explorer by clicking on it?

Thank you for helping me out. If anything is unclear, you can ask me anytime!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dedicated label using the `for` attribute and hide your usual file upload entirely

```
 <label for="fileupload">Drag folder</label>
 <div class="upload-folder" style="display:none">
   <input id="fileupload" type="file" id="file" webkitdirectory multiple (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">

   <button (click)="uploadFiles()">Upload</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Yes, the file upload is hidden but clicking on the label does not open the Windows-Explorer. What could I have done wrong?

Comment: Mmh, it works as expected for me. Try the following fiddle with the exact same code above. Clicking on the text "Drag folder" opens the windows explorer to select a file https://jsfiddle.net/lubber/4172qpaL/2/

Comment: You may have missed adding an id to the input field. Otherwise the `for` attribute does not know where it belongs to (and will not open the explorer then)

Comment: It is working but in my chrome browser the text ```Choose File No File Selected``` is still displayed but why? In your example only ``` Drag Folder ``` is displayed not the rest. EDIT: Missed ```style="display:none" ```